# How to name PDFs with items in a list (titles of graphs in ggplot), R?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am attempting to output a set of graphs (as PDFs) which I have turned into a list. I want their ID to be in the title of the PDF name.

To create the list I am doing this:

`` All_Plots=dlply(Data, .(`ID`),function(x) Plots %+% x +facet_wrap(~ID)) ``

Next, I want to get out of the PDFs out with their 'ID', which is the title of each plot

I was using this:

```
pdf(file="%03Plot.pdf", onefile=FALSE, paper="a4r", width=14)
All_Plots
dev.off()
```

But it will only give me numbers and not the IDs. I am wondering if I should use paste0?

```
pdf(file=paste0(Data$ID, "%03Plot.pdf"), onefile=FALSE, paper="a4r", width=14)
```

This gives me the first ID in the data frame but not the rest

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: I think your solution doesn't work like that. AFAICS, the parameterized `file` argument is hardcoded in a a call to an external C function. Best to loop over your `ID` values yourself and `paste0()`ing your filename together in the loop.

Comment: Ok, thank you @PaulLemmens  I am trying to get something to work, but getting the same result:
  
`
for(i in All_Plots) {
  files <- file.path(paste0(Data$ID, "_%0dXXX.pdf"))
  pdf(file=files, onefile=FALSE, paper="a4r", width=14) 
}
`

Comment: `%` is not allowed in filenames, in most filesystems / OSes. And what is stored in `Data$ID`? If it is a vector of all IDs, then for the filename it will always use the first.

Comment: @question You seem to be struggling with a couple of basic concepts. If you need to construct the filename manually, there's no need to use the `%d` (etc) syntax unless you construct the names using `sprintf()`. For this to work, you either need to have the `ID` value inside your all plots object, or you need to loop over indices instead of elements of `All_Plots` so that you can index both `All_Plots[[i]]` and `Data$ID[i]`.

Comment: @PaulLemmens thanks for your help... I apologize, I am a bit out of my area of knowledge so I appreciate your help. I don't really have experience with for loops.
Here is where I am at:
 ` 
for(i in length(All_Plots)){
  pdf(file = (paste0(IDS, "XX.pdf")), onefile=FALSE, paper="a4r", width=14) 
}
`
I think I am missing some stuff or a basic concept with these loops

Comment: @question, you're getting there. The basic approach is `for (i in 1:length(all_plots)) { pdf(paste0(ids[i], 'XX.pdf')); plot(all_plots[i]); dev.off() }`. `length(x)` only gives the length, not the vector to iterate over. Therefore you need `1:length(x)`. In the `paste0()`, also index `ids` to get the id that matches your plot. This is prefixed before `XX.pdf`; so the XX is not replaced with something (but it may have been your pseudocode).